# SQL Error Missing Right Paretheses

Tags: sql, database, oracle, syntax-error

I am just learning SQL and when I try to create the "Order" table I get the error "missing right parentheses". When I remove the FK constraint I get the error "invalid identifier"

```
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
CUST_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
COMP_NAME VARCHAR(40),
CONT_LNAME VARCHAR(30),
CONT_FNAME VARCHAR(30),
PHONE VARCHAR(30),
EMAIL VARCHAR(40),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(40),
CITY VARCHAR(30),
ZIP NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_ID, COMP_NAME, CONT_LNAME, CONT_FNAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, CITY,ZIP) VALUES 
(1,'Atomic Liqours','Signor','Rose','518-990-8765','rose@atomicliqours.com','76 Hackett Blvd','Albany','12204');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_ID, COMP_NAME, CONT_LNAME, CONT_FNAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, CITY,ZIP) VALUES 
(2,'HBD Bar','Capozolli','Rose','889-908-6666','rose@hbd.com','888 Project Rd','Troy','12180');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (CUST_ID, COMP_NAME, CONT_LNAME, CONT_FNAME, PHONE, EMAIL, ADDRESS, CITY,ZIP) VALUES 
(3,'Lee Harvey','Smith','Seth','675-888-9999','seth@lh.com','78 Healy Ave','Troy','12222');
-- CREATING ORDER TABLE
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
ORD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers (CUST_ID),
ORD_DATE DATE,
DEL_DATE DATE,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your have a typo in your script. Your table name is `CUSTOMER`, but in `CREATE TABLE` you references to `CUSTOMERS`. So, I think that your create table statement must looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
ORD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer (CUST_ID),
ORD_DATE DATE,
DEL_DATE DATE,
);
```

Comment: I just tried that but am still getting the same error

Comment: try to remove `FOREIGN KEY`, so line will looks like:
`CUST_ID INT REFERENCES Customer (CUST_ID),`

Comment: I get the error invalid identifier, I also get this same error if I remove that entire line

Comment: That extra comma on the `DEL_DATE` line is going to be a syntax problem.

Comment: Could you please show the full text of error message?

Comment: Or you can try this syntax of create table:
`CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
ORD_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
CUST_ID INT,ORD_DATE DATE,
DEL_DATE DATE,
Constraint CUSTOMER_FK FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUST_ID)
);`